# Is there any static friction when pulling a trolley?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

A trolley consists of 4 steel wheels and trolley is placed on steel track. The trolley consists of load, and when it is pulled, is there any static friction involved? What is direction of static friction? What are the factors influencing the static friction?

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question is entirely conceptual - there are no calculations involved.

Answer (score 1):

There is static friction at the point where the wheels of the trolley contact the ground. The static friction vector would be tangent to the wheel and parallel to the ground, and in the opposite direction of the direction the trolley is pulled, and is what is responsible for the torque causing the wheels to rotate and roll instead of just sliding across the floor.

Since when an object is rolling, the point of the wheel that is contacting the ground is actually not moving, this would be static friction.

Comment: Will Static friction also acts in case of starting trolley?

Comment: @Nitheeswar If the trolley is *pulled* then there may or may not be static friction between the wheels and the track - as the answer says, if there is no static friction then the wheels will simply slide along the track instead of turning. However, if the trolley is self-propelled by a motor that exerts a torque on the wheels, then there must be static friction for the trolley to move forwards.

Comment: Let us consider the Trolley is being pulled by a winch,I think in this case static friction opposes the motion right?

Comment: Static friction depends on mass of wheel. Will static friction depends upon the mass present  on the Trolley?

Comment: @Nitheeswar Only if there is dynamic friction between the trolley and the axle. Assuming the 'wheel bearings' are frictionless, nope.